# Laravel passing data using ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

How do I pass the id from this ajax call to the TestController getAjax() function? When I do the call the url is testUrl?id=1

```
Route::get('testUrl', 'TestController@getAjax');

<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testUrl',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: 1 },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#something').html(response);
                }
            });
       });
    });    
</script>
```

TestController.php

```
public function getAjax()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $test = new TestModel();
    $result = $test->getData($id);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $html =
              '<tr>
                 <td>' . $row->name . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->address . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->age . '</td>' .
              '</tr>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the end, I just added the parameter to the Route::get() and in the ajax url call too. I changed $_POST['id'] to $_GET['id'] in the getAjax() function and this got my response back

```
Route::get('testUrl/{id}', 'TestController@getAjax');

<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testUrl/{id}',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: 1 },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#something').html(response);
                }
            });
       });
    });    
</script>
```

TestController.php

```
public function getAjax()
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $test = new TestModel();
    $result = $test->getData($id);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $html =
              '<tr>
                 <td>' . $row->name . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->address . '</td>' .
                 '<td>' . $row->age . '</td>' .
              '</tr>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$id = $_GET['id'];` i used `Input::get("id")` anyways it works thx alot

Answer (score 7):

Your ajax's method is GET but in controller you use $_POST to get
   value. This is problem.

You can you

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

But in Laravel, it have a pretty method to do this. It's [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input). You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb used for the request, as input is accessed in the same way for all verbs.

```
$id = Input::get("id");
```

If you want, you can filter request type to control exception. [Docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information)

Determine If The Request Is Using AJAX

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to specify a route for the url in the $.ajax call?

Comment: $.ajax or $.post is the same in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
#in your controller function    
public function getAjax()
{
    #check if request is ajax
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        //your code
    }

    return $your_data;
}
```