# Send two parameters with ajax get method when using laravel's route contoller

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

Suppose that we have a controller and route like this:

```
Route::controller('/test', TestController);
```

And we also have controller method,

```
public function getIndex($data)
{
  return $data;
}
```

And this is ok with ajax, get method

```
$.ajax(
 {
  url: '/test/' + data //this data comes from some hidden input
  success: function(e){
  console.log(e);
  }
 }

);
```

But how will i send two parameters to controller, i don't know. Thanks for help.

Comment: what does "data" output (the hidden input)?

Comment: here's an example of how you would send data to the controller. you can have more objects than just "id" in there, same principle applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413062/3036342

Answer (score 1):

It's not always the ideal way but you can just add parameters as much as you want:

```
url: '/test/' + data + '/' + foo + '/' + bar,
```

And receive them like this:

```
public function getIndex($data, $foo, $bar)
{
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to use GET? A cleaner way would be to use POST, like this:

```
public function postIndex()
{
    $arg1 = Request::input('argument1');
    $arg2 = Request::input('argument2');
    //etc...

    return Request::all();
}
```

The ajax call:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('/test') }}',
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    'argument1': argument1,
                    'argument2': argument2,
                    'argument3': argument3,
                    '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
               .... do something with your returned data, if needed;
            }).fail(function(e){
                console.log(e); // gives your something to debug.
            });
```

Comment: is using post ideal for select from database? for REST rule?