# Laravel 5 No query results for model redirect page

Tags: laravel, view, eloquent

I have simple form that post values to a controller,everything works fine if a result is returned from the controller , but if there is no result I get error the following error:

`No query results for model`

Which works as it should.

My question is :

Is it possible if no result is found to redirect to another view and display a message?

I tried this,with no result:

```
try {
                     $postal = $request->input('postal');
                     $get_all=  Geo_Postal_us::where('postal', $postal)->firstOrFail();  
                     $count=count($get_all);
                     return view('test.show',compact('get_all','count'));

                } catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
                    return Redirect::to('view.404');
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Suggestion 1

```
      $postal = $request->input('postal');
      $get_all=  Geo_Postal_us::where('postal', $postal)->first();  
      if($get_all)
        {
            $count=count($get_all);
            return view('test.show',compact('get_all','count'));
        }
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','No results found');
```

This will check if `get_all` is found and if is found will return `test.show` view else will redirect to previous view with message `No results found` .

If you want to declare an exception do so in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file.
Example:

## Suggestion 2

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {   
    //If model  not found return views/errors/404.blade.php page. 
       if ($e instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException)
        {
        return response(view('errors.error_404'),404);
            
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
```

P.S - I don't understand why you have to use `count()` . Method `first()` will always return a single result. Better try `get()`

Comment: Tnx for quick response, I try first option,here is problem:   return redirect->back()->with('message','No results found'); , ----------------- Get this : syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: Sorry for this I assume you are using laravel 4?
I wrote this answer with laravel 5 in mind. I edited my question. Just edit `redirect()->back()->with('message','No results found')` with `Redirect::back()->with('message','No results found')` . Laravel 4 uses the facade instead of the redirector instance.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer..Trz this,but again get error No query results for model [App\Geo_Postal_us].

Comment: Well, it seems `firstOrFail` method is throwing an `ModelNotFoundException` as soon as it finds out there is not a model matching the `$postal` variable. So either tr to declare an exception in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file like the answer I provided. Or just use `->first()` and do the check manually

Comment: Yeah, that was my option too.I try something similar that is your answer,I yust try tro redirect to custom view if count of returner field iz less then 1,but no success

Comment: I have updated my answer try suggestion one. Just use `first()` instead of `firstOrFail`

Comment: I just forget tu put this : use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

Comment: Do yuo have any suggestion about link for ajax posting data to controller in LAravel 5 ? I try a lot,but no success :) I just need,tafter form subbmit,to post data to controller,and than return that in view

Comment: For ajax you just need to write a javascript script that points to a `route ` that uses a controller method that does the post/get actions for you. It's not that complicated really.Just fire that ajax script on a "click/change" event and you are ok :)

Comment: I try something like this :                                                                      <script>
 
$("document").ready(function(){
 $("#frm").submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var postal = $("input[name=postal]").val();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url : "http://laravel.test/ajax2",
 data : dataString,
 dataType : "json",
 success : function(data){

}
 
},"json");
 
});
 });//end of document ready function
 </script>                                                                                                  ROUTE: Route::post('ajax2', 'TestController@ajax2');

Comment: But,I cant submitt form ,I am working now on that :)

Comment: Please open a new question. This code is not even readable as a comment :P

Comment: No problem . 
Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351085/laravel-passing-data-using-ajax-to-controller

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I place index route after single singe list. Then I just place index task before single list. Then it's works. Something like this:

```
Route::get('index', 'TasksController@index');

Route::get('/{task}', 'TasksController@single');
```

Comment: This solution works, still don't understand what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as well .  i have 2 suggestion, **suggestion1** place the route that result in error above the others . **suggestion2** be sure you have not route with the same name even which controlled by different Controller

this is the exact problem that I face b/c of

```
$api->post('update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update');
$api->post('update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@update');
```