# laravel , ajax not working in production mode The requested URL /appointment/45/edit was not found on this server

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to update data using ajax and laravel it working in local but in production, it's given me an error    (The requested URL /appointment/45/edit was not found on this server)

I am using ajax, laravel 5.7

```
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
             url: "/appointment/" + id + "/edit",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(html) {
                $('#name').val(html.data.name);
                $('#appdate').val(html.data.appdate);
                $('.modal-title').text("Edit Appointment");
                $('#action_button').val("Edit");
                $('#action').val("Edit");
                $('#modal-default').modal('show');
            }
        })
    });



route
Route::resource('appointment','AppointmentController');



controller
    public function edit($id)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $data = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

The requested URL /appointment/45/edit was not found on this server

I try to update data using ajax and laravel it working in local but in production, it's giving me an error    (The requested URL /appointment/45/edit was not found on this server)

Comment: Your route should be something like `Route::resource('/appointment/{id}/edit','AppointmentController@edit');`

Comment: thank you bassxzero, but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call use named route like

> url:'{{route('route.name')}}'

And also add ajax call type

> type:'post' or type:'get'

Comment: how to add parameter with this router,  url: "{{ route('appointment.edit') }} " + id ,

Comment: as you add with route in controller like:  url:{{ route('appointment.edit', 'id' ) }}... Here id is javascript variable you have to create before sending ajax request.

Comment: if you are sending get request than just add with 'data' property of ajax request like:-- data:{ id : id }

Comment: watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351085/laravel-passing-data-using-ajax-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

In js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/appointment/" + id + "/edit",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#name').val(response.data.name);
            $('#appdate').val(response.data.appdate);
            $('.modal-title').text("Edit Appointment");
            $('#action_button').val("Edit");
            $('#action').val("Edit");
            $('#modal-default').modal('show');
        }
    })
});
```

In route file (web.php)

```
Route::resource('appointment','AppointmentController');
```

In controller:

```
    public function edit($id)
    {     
         $data = Appointment::findOrFail($id);
         return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
    }
```