# Send data to Laravel controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, controller, laravel-6

I'm trying to send POST request to a Laravel controller using ajax, BUT nothin happen

#### Script

```
<script>
(function($) {
    jQuery('#categorie,#marque').change(function () {
        var id_marq=$('#marque').val();
        var id_cat=$('#categorie').val();
        var url = $('#application_url').val();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: url+"/produits/ajoutPrixProduit",
            type:"POST",
            data:{'id_cat':id_cat, 'id_marq':id_marq},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                    $('#nom').append('<option value="' + key.id + '">' + value.libelle + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

#### Route

```
Route::post('/produits/ajoutPrixProduit', 'MagasinBoardController@selProduit')->name('magasin.selProduit');
```

#### Controller

```
public function selProduit(Request $request)
{
    $id_cat=$request->id_cat;
    $id_marq=$request->id_marq;
   .......
    return response()->json($listProd); 
}
```

I don't know why and how to fix it

Comment: if you check developer console in client it return which http status code? 200?

Comment: The http status code is 200

Comment: In your controller, if you `return $request->all();` what do you get in the dev console? Your jquery is a bit confusing to me. It's probably not wrong. Only written in a style I'm not used to.

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26413062/13056147