# Fetch data in PHP controller passed through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to pass all variable data to PHP(Laravel) controller, so as to proceed with other operations with those variables in controller. Here when I do as per below mentioned code, I get response "hello" as output in console. But how do I take input in controller.

Route (web.php)

```
Route::get('invoice_data_process', 'App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController@invoiceDataProcess');
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $("#print_invoice").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
            const arr = $("#rowData [id^=product_id]")
                .map(function() {
                    const $qnty = $(this).closest("tr").find("[id^=product_qnty]")
                    return ({
                        [$(this).attr("id")]: $(this).val(),
                        [$qnty.attr("id")]: $qnty.val()
                    })
                })
                .get();
            var invoiceNo = $('#invoiceNo').val();
            var invoiceDate = $('#invoiceDate').val();
            var clientName = $('#clientName').val();
            var grandTotal = $('#grandtotal').val();
            console.log(arr)


            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                    url: '{{ URL::to('/invoice_data_process') }}', // Controller/View
                    data: { //Passing data
                        'invoiceNo' : invoiceNo,
                        'invoiceDate' : invoiceDate,
                        'clientName' : clientName,
                        'grandTotal' : grandTotal,
                        'arr' : arr
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("hello");

                    },

                });

        });
    });
```

Controller.php

```
public function invoiceDataProcess(Request $request)
{
    $invoice_number = $request->get('invoiceNo');
    $invoice_number = $request->get('invoiceDate');
    $client_name = $request->get('ClientName');
    $grand_total = $request->get('grandTotal');
    $arr = $request->get('arr');

    print_r( $invoice_number );
    die;
}
```

Header

```
<head>
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

Output (http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoice_data_process)

Blank Page

Comment: Follow this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351085/laravel-passing-data-using-ajax-to-controller

Comment: You have the route defined as `Route::get`, but you're trying to POST to it. Won't work

Comment: @aynber I used POST as well, but shows error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use both POST and GET for the same route. You'll need to create a route for each method, or use `Route::match(['get', 'post']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel passing data using ajax to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351085/laravel-passing-data-using-ajax-to-controller)